# Angular - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'AbstractControl' has no index signature

Tags: angular

In my Angular-11, I have this code in the typescript:

```
multistep = new FormGroup({
      userDetails: new FormGroup({
        first_name: new FormControl(''),
        last_name: new FormControl(''),
        other_name: new FormControl(''),
        email: new FormControl(''),
        mobile_number: new FormControl(''),
        gender: new FormControl(''),
        marital_status: new FormControl(''),
        employee_photo: new FormControl('')
      })
});

get userDetails(){
   return this.multistep.controls['userDetails']['controls'];
 }
```

But I got this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'AbstractControl' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'get'?

and this is highlighted:

> this.multistep.controls['userDetails']['controls'];

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Comment: The error is telling you how to fix the issue. Instead of using bracket syntax, use: `this.multistep.get('userDetails') as FormGroup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast userDetails to FormGroup `userDetails as FormGroup`.

```
  get userDetails(){
    return (this.multistep.controls.userDetails as FormGroup).controls;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this instead:

```
this.multistep.get('userDetails').controls
```

The get method is the way to access controls within a formGroup